# Getting d3.js to label "00 02 04..." as "12AM 2AM 4AM..." in d3.scale.linear()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data that is already sorted by the hour so the "hour" value is an integer from 00 (12am) to 23 (11pm).

I am trying to plot this data as a scatterplot using d3.js.

Since the hourly data is already in an integer form, I thought it would be easier to just use a `d3.scale.linear().domain([-1,23])` to plot the points out (using -1 as the lower bound so that the midnight data does not overlap the y axis). So far this has been successful, but now the labels in the x-axis show "0 2  4  6  8 ..." etc.

How can I convert this to the actual hour (ie 12AM, 2AM, 4AM... etc)? I have tried using `.tickValues( ['12AM', '2AM', '4AM'... etc] )` but this produces a `NaN` in the output and console.

Is it possible to specify custom axis labels like this? Or would I have to read the `hour` value in properly as a time scale and parse it as `"%H"`, instead of simply using a linear scale?

Here's a jsfiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jqw7a9mu/1/

Thanks!

Comment: Is it exactly time of specific day or just an integers you want format like am/pm time format?

Comment: I'm not very sure what you mean - are you asking if I have integers that I just want converted to AM/PM without minutes? If so, then yes - all the observations are on the hour, and I just want to label it as such (ie 8AM, 10AM, 12PM, 2PM...)

Comment: Yes, I mean is it necessary to convert your integers to the time of you can use just labels formatter function?

Comment: Can you "jsfiddle" or "jsbin" your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append `.tickFormat()` method for `xAxis` variable:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
                var f = ["12AM", "1AM", "2AM", "3AM", "4AM", "5AM", "6AM", "7AM", "8AM", "9AM", "10AM", "11AM", "12PM", "1PM", "2PM", "3PM", "4PM", "5PM", "6PM", "7PM", "8PM", "9PM", "10PM", "11PM"];
            return (f[d]);
        });
```

This method creates desirable captions:

[image]

If you want force d3.js not skip 1AM, 3AM etc., you should use `.tickValues()` method:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
                var f = ["12AM", "1AM", "2AM", "3AM", "4AM", "5AM", "6AM", "7AM", "8AM", "9AM", "10AM", "11AM", "12PM", "1PM", "2PM", "3PM", "4PM", "5PM", "6PM", "7PM", "8PM", "9PM", "10PM", "11PM"];
            return (f[d]);
        })
        .tickValues([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]);
```

In this case the final picture will be:

[image]

But you should consider the horizontal size of the graph.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qy5ohw0x/2/

Comment: Thanks for trying, however this doesn't work. It seems like it's mapping the `hour` values in my dataset to "12AM", "1AM", etc, but then d3.js doesn't know how to scale these values anymore so all my data points end up on one end. I've updated my question with a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! I did not think about using `tickFormat` in this way. And yes, I didn't want to force all the hours with `tickValues` to reduce clutter.